# setting arguments for class while running on server

Tags: java, pentaho, kettle, jvm-arguments

I am connecting Pentaho Kettle from Java program.

While running the class as standalone, I have to set vm-arguments as -

```
DKETTLE_PLUGIN_BASE_FOLDERS=E:/data-integration/plugins
```

and it is working fine.

But how to achieve the same while running the class on the server? If i run the class on server, it says plugins not found.

Answer (score 0):

Its the same. The only difference is - while running as standalone, we have to set it at class level. ie Rightclick at class run config- set vm args and while setting for run time, you can set it server level. Same right click, instead of Java application, just set it for you server.